# Is it possible to programatically extract a spotify playlist?

Tags: php, extract

I have done a load of searching but haven't found anything. There seem to be a lot of jobs asking for this functionality yet no one really talking about whether / how it can be done.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so where I could extract the data from?

Comment: see answers from similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490137/spotify-api-to-get-playlists-of-a-user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the official [libspotify documentation](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/) and more specifically the [playlist subsystem](http://developer.spotify.com/en/libspotify/docs/group__playlist.html).

Note that this is a C API, not PHP.