# spotify api to get playlists of a user

Tags: php, spotify

i need to use the api of [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com) my client needs to have a spotify application that will connect to the spotify on behalf of the registered user and will fetch all the playlist names and their songs in those playlist, and will make a txt file of those playlist, thats it. 
please help me where should i start , i need to get it done with php.

Thanks

Comment: Did you search any thing on it? what data you found about this ?

Comment: i searched but not found any related info

Comment: check these out,http://www.spotify.com/fi/about/spotify-on-the-web/developer-resources/ and http://code.google.com/p/metatune/ and http://code.google.com/p/metatune/wiki/FeatureList

Comment: @Muhammad Zeeshan Thanks , Let i try

Comment: i got a premium account and got api key from spotify, now did not finding a way to get the playlist of user

Comment: http://nrkbeta.no/2009/10/29/nrk-p3-spotify-playlists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was solved by just backing up the playlist.bnk file. which contains the files for playslists

Comment: the file is actually called playlist.bnk

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, there is a lot of code circling around using the unfortunate not open source libspotify. The API examples provided, carefully omitting a way to iterate over all playlists.

You mention that you want something that can connect to spotify (the online API is certainly what Spotify would like everyone to use) but I'm pretty sure the same can be done offline. As you said yourself, the files can be backed up.

Located in:

~/.config/spotify/Users/name/

or

{USER_APP_DATA}/Spotify/Users/{USER_ID}

You can probably already tell I'm not a fan of proprietary libraries restricting access to what I can or can not do. So I came up with a simple program that can print the names of all stored playlists. This is helpful enough because I usually add one album per playlist.

I'm pretty sure it can be developed further to include individual tracks.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<char> vbuf;
    unsigned int len;
    std::vector<char>::iterator bpos,dpos,epos;

    std::ifstream in("playlist.bnk", std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    if (in) {
        in.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
        len = in.tellg();
        vbuf.resize(len);
        in.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&vbuf[0],len);

        for(std::vector<char>::iterator it = vbuf.begin(); it != vbuf.end(); ++it) {
            if (*it == (char)0x02 && *(it+1) == (char)0x09) {
                bpos = it+3;
            }                                                                                          
            if (*it == (char)0xE2 && *(it+1) == (char)0x80 && *(it+2) == (char)0x93 && bpos != vbuf.end()) {
                dpos = it;
            }                                                                                          
            if (*it == (char)0x18 && *(it+1) == (char)0x01 && *(it+2) == (char)0x19 && dpos != vbuf.end()) {
                epos = it;
            }                                                                   
            if (bpos != vbuf.end() && dpos != vbuf.end() && epos != vbuf.end()) {
                for(std::vector<char>::iterator it2 = bpos; it2 < dpos; ++it2) {
                    std::cout << *it2;
                }                                                              
                for(std::vector<char>::iterator it2 = dpos; it2 < epos; ++it2) {
                    std::cout << *it2;
                }
                std::cout << std::endl;
                bpos = vbuf.end();
                dpos = vbuf.end();
                epos = vbuf.end();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kasreyn, unfortunately your code stopped working. It just outputs just some 'random' song. Can you update it or post information how you implemented it. I don't understand the parsing. Thanks!