# Is it possible to get a list of followed artists using libspotify?

Tags: c, spotify, libspotify

I have looked at the [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.45/) documentation and have not been able to find a function that allows me to get a list of handles to artists that the current user is following. Is there something I have missed or is it just not part of the public API yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, **No**.

However, you may want to take a look at these other Q&As that manage to overcome the limitations of the API by implementing their own workarounds with the info available.

- [Obtaining a list of artists from the user's favorite tracks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726308/obtaining-a-lists-of-artists-using-cocoalibspotify-for-ios).
- [Parsing the local `playlist.bnk` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490137/spotify-api-to-get-playlists-of-a-user).